# Using bash and curl to do multiple posts

Tags: bash, curl

This is what I have done so far;

```
#!/bin/bash

url="asdf.com/check  "
for i in $(cat query.txt); do
    content=$"curl --data "email=$i" "$url")"
    echo "$content" >> output.txt
done
```

Comment: What problem are you encountering exactly? Your code has some issues but it is difficult to guess what errors you get and what the intended behavior should be

Answer (score 0):

You can use your loop like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

url="asdf.com/check"

while read -r line; do
   curl --data "email=$line" "$url"
done < query.txt > output.txt
```

You can use output redirection only once just after the `done` as shown.

Comment: Thank you it is running the curl command now but nothing is showing up in output.txt

Comment: Do you see any output on terminal if you remove `> output.txt` from above command?